# Inserting Username token in security header of already generated SOAP envelope gives me two headers!

Tags: java, web-services, security, wss4j, usernametoken

I'm using WSS4J to add a Username token in the header of an already formed SOAP request envelope.

Here is what the SOAP request looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://sample03.samples.rampart.apache.org/xsd">   
   <soapenv:Header/>   
   <soapenv:Body>      
      <xsd:echo>         
         <xsd:param0>hurro kitty</xsd:param0>      
      </xsd:echo>   
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my code (the String, request, is the request above):

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(request));
Document document = builder.parse(inStream);

WSSecUsernameToken usernametoken = new WSSecUsernameToken();
usernametoken.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
usernametoken.setUserInfo(username, password);

WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader("", false);
secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(document);
usernametoken.build(document, secHeader);
```

This is my result (notice the header that was inserted is not namespaced correctly, as well as there being two headers):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://sample03.samples.rampart.apache.org/xsd">   
   <Header>      
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">         
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2765109" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">            
            <wsse:Username>bob</wsse:Username>            
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">bobPW</wsse:Password>         
         </wsse:UsernameToken>      
      </wsse:Security>   
   </Header>   
   <soapenv:Header/>   
   <soapenv:Body>      
      <xsd:echo>         
         <xsd:param0>hurro kitty</xsd:param0>      
      </xsd:echo>   
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

When you are building the initial XML, you need to make sure that the DocumentBuilderFactory is namespace-aware.  WSSecurity is trying to find the soap header by the soap namespace but it isn't available.  Adding the following line should fix it:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
...
```